# Term by term differentiation of unordered sum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, reference-request

Consider the unordered sum
$$
\text{"}f(x)=\sum_{\mathbf{n}\in I}c_{\mathbf{n}}f_{\mathbf{n}}(x)\text{"},
$$
where the $I$ consists of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (so that it is a countable sum).

Under what sort of convergence do we have "$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\sum_{\mathbf{n}\in I}c_{\mathbf{n}}\frac{d}{dx}f_{\mathbf{n}}(x)$" and what sort of convergence do we have for this differentiated version? Or what should I read?

==========================================

I know for a function series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nf_n(x)$ the condition for the term-wise differentiation is well known.

I know that for a double series or $m$-indexed series $\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}a_{j,k}$ the absolute convergence allows us to change the order.

Thus I think for $\sum_{j,k=0}^{\infty}c_{j,k}f_{j,k}$ we can make the series "one line" first and then resort it to the usual case.

But I haven't a clue when the index $\mathbf{n}$ can be arbitrarily finite.

For example if $\{f_{\mathbf{n}}\}$, ($f_{\mathbf{n}}:X\to\mathbb{R}$, say) is a complete orthonormal system (net) in a Hilbert space that happen to be a set of function over $X$, I am ok with the convergence but I am not familiar with the term-wise differentiation etc.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen it done is that if one has a sequence $(a_n)$ then for any permutation (that is, a bijection) $\pi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, one can consider the sequence $a_{\pi(n)}.$ It is possible to prove that 
$$\exists S\quad\forall\pi\quad \sum_n a_{\pi(n)}\;\text{converges to }S\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\sum_n \left|a_n\right|\;\text{converges}.$$
In fact if a series converges but not absolutely then you can make it converge any value you like by reordering terms.

*Edit:* Having re-read your question, I realise that I don't address most of the points. I can't quite tell what you're asking but to me it seems that you may want to look into other notions of convergence (especially for function series, e.g. uniform, absolute uniform, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question. The last comment of yours, how do we even define the series or convergence is indeed part of my question and I did not explain it clearly.

Comment: I think uniform continuity is probably the thing to look into here. There are theorems about convergence of derivatives, integrals, etc for uniformly convergent series. It may be worth brushing up on more basic real analysis a lot first.